# editing database for azure mobile services using Azure SQL management portal

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, windows-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I am developing windows 8.1 application and using AZURE mobile services to communicate with. I need have some data in azure mobile services database which will be dumped to application when it's installed on any device. So I tried to add records in the database using azure management portal SQL_database but seems like I cant do that it gives me error

```
"Cannot add a row in the Table Data Editor because one or more columns are required but their SQL types are not supported in Table Data Editor. Use the Transact-SQL Editor to add a row."
```

This is probably due to the --version column that has binary type . So I tried deleting this column but then there was following error

```
"The target table 'ShoppingListPro.Category' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause."
```

I googled this issue and what I found is Link .

Please guide me if it is possible to edit the azure mobile service data base using management portal that will make my life bit easy , other wise I need to write an app to feed data to azure mobile database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to the DB from SSMS. Just check what your connection string is below 'Connect to your database':

[image]